# How to use a lot of xsd-files with only one namespace and see a tooltips in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: xml, spring, xsd, intellij-idea

I have some problems with tooltips in IntelliJ Idea 11.1.4

I have a project, in which i use **spring** for configuration.

When I want to compose a lot of xsd files in one, tooltips does't works. I show you an example.
In **spring.schemas** we have two records

```
http\://www.example.com/schema/test.xsd=test-schema.xsd
http\://www.example.com/schema/test-in.xsd=test-schema-in.xsd
```

**test-schema-in.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.example.com/schema/test"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/schema/test"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:element name="name-element" type="type1"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="type1">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="beans:identifiedType">
                <xsd:all>
                    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:all>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

**test-schema.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.example.com/schema/test"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/schema/test"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:include schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/schema/test-in.xsd"/>

    <xsd:element name="age-element" type="type2"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="type2">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="beans:identifiedType">
                <xsd:all>
                    <xsd:element name="age" type="xsd:integer"/>
                </xsd:all>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

And we have such simple xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:ex="http://www.example.com/schema/test"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.example.com/schema/test
       http://www.example.com/schema/test.xsd">

    <ex:age-element>
        <ex:age>
            3
        </ex:age>
    </ex:age-element>

    <ex:name-element>
        <ex:name >
            Simple Name
        </ex:name>
    </ex:name-element>

</beans>
```

In tooltips I can see **age-element**, but can't see **name-element**.

Is there a solution to use a lot of xsd-files with one namespace(with include) and see elements in **Idea tooltips** ??